# Making PANDAS identify a PATTERN inside a value on a DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Python 3.9 with Pandas and Numpy.

Every day I receive a df with orders from the company I work for. Each day, this df comes from a different country that I don't know the language, and this dataframes don't have a pattern. In this case, **I don't know what's the column name nor the index.**

I just know that the orders follows a patter: 3 numbers + 2 letters like 000AA, 149KL, 555EE etc.

I saw that with strings is possible, but with pandas I just found commands that needs the name of the column.

```py
df.column_name.str.contains(pat=r'\d\d\d\w\w', regex=True)
```

If I can find the column that only have this pattern, I know what the orders column is.

Comment: Could you provide an example dataframe? What would the content look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with a synthetic data set

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'a':3,'b':4,'c':'222BB','d':'2asf'},
                       {'a':2,'b':1,'c':'111AA','d':'942'}])
```

I then cycle through each column. If the datatype is `object`, then I test whether all the elements in the Series match the regex

```py
for column_id in df.columns:
    if df[column_id].dtype=='object':
        if all(df[column_id].str.contains(pat=r'\d\d\d\w\w', regex=True)):
            print("matching column:",column_id)
```

Comment: Thx!! The both answers I got works, but I choose yours because I found it simpler